# BouncyCastle does not find algorithms that it provides?

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I'm playing around with [BouncyCastle 1.46](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) To my surprise, the catch-block in the snippet below is tripped quite often.

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

final Set<String> found = new HashSet<String>();
final Set<String> missing = new HashSet<String>();

final DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder finder = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder();
for (Service service : new BouncyCastleProvider().getServices()) {
    if ("Signature".equals(service.getType())) {
        final String algorithm = service.getAlgorithm();
        try {
            finder.find(algorithm);
            found.add(algorithm);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            missing.add(algorithm);
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Found: " + found);
System.out.println("Missing: " + missing);
```

I appear to be unable to use most of the algorithms through the Finder, even though Services exist that provide those algorithms. What am I doing wrong?

*Update* I've changed the code a little to illustrate the issue better. What might be of interest is that I am using the JDK1.5 version of BouncyCastle. The code above gives this output:

Found: [RIPEMD256WithRSAEncryption, MD5WithRSAEncryption, MD2WithRSAEncryption, SHA384WithRSAEncryption, SHA224WITHECDSA, SHA384WITHDSA, SHA256WITHDSA, SHA512WithRSAEncryption, SHA512WITHDSA, RIPEMD160WithRSAEncryption, SHA224WithRSAEncryption, SHA256WITHECDSA, RIPEMD128WithRSAEncryption, SHA384WITHECDSA, SHA256WithRSAEncryption, SHA512WITHECDSA, SHA1WithRSAEncryption, SHA224WITHDSA]

Missing: [SHA1WITHECNR, NONEwithECDSA, ECDSA, SHA512withRSA/PSS, RIPEMD160WITHECDSA, RSA, GOST3410, SHA256WITHECNR, MD5withRSA/ISO9796-2, SHA1WITHCVC-ECDSA, SHA384withRSA/PSS, SHA1withRSA/PSS, MD4WithRSAEncryption, RSASSA-PSS, SHA512WITHECNR, SHA256WITHCVC-ECDSA, SHA1withRSA/ISO9796-2, SHA224withRSA/PSS, SHA224WITHCVC-ECDSA, RAWRSASSA-PSS, SHA256withRSA/PSS, NONEWITHDSA, SHA384WITHECNR, RIPEMD160withRSA/ISO9796-2, DSA, ECGOST3410, SHA224WITHECNR, 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10]

Comment: Can you debug it and add to your question what's being returned in `service.getAlgorithm()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that `DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder` is part of the bcmail API. It returns algorithm identifiers recognized by this API. (Check [Cryptographic Message Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652)) On the other hand the bouncy castle provider provides more algorithms. You may check the source of `DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder` where the recognized algorithms are hardcoded:

```
algorithms.put("MD2WITHRSAENCRYPTION", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.md2WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("MD2WITHRSA", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.md2WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("MD5WITHRSAENCRYPTION", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.md5WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("MD5WITHRSA", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.md5WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA1WITHRSAENCRYPTION", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha1WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA1WITHRSA", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha1WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA224WITHRSAENCRYPTION", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha224WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA224WITHRSA", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha224WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA256WITHRSAENCRYPTION", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha256WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA256WITHRSA", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha256WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA384WITHRSAENCRYPTION", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha384WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA384WITHRSA", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha384WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA512WITHRSAENCRYPTION", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha512WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA512WITHRSA", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha512WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA1WITHRSAANDMGF1", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSASSA_PSS);
algorithms.put("SHA224WITHRSAANDMGF1", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSASSA_PSS);
algorithms.put("SHA256WITHRSAANDMGF1", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSASSA_PSS);
algorithms.put("SHA384WITHRSAANDMGF1", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSASSA_PSS);
algorithms.put("SHA512WITHRSAANDMGF1", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSASSA_PSS);
algorithms.put("RIPEMD160WITHRSAENCRYPTION", TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.rsaSignatureWithripemd160);
algorithms.put("RIPEMD160WITHRSA", TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.rsaSignatureWithripemd160);
algorithms.put("RIPEMD128WITHRSAENCRYPTION", TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.rsaSignatureWithripemd128);
algorithms.put("RIPEMD128WITHRSA", TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.rsaSignatureWithripemd128);
algorithms.put("RIPEMD256WITHRSAENCRYPTION", TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.rsaSignatureWithripemd256);
algorithms.put("RIPEMD256WITHRSA", TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.rsaSignatureWithripemd256);
algorithms.put("SHA1WITHDSA", X9ObjectIdentifiers.id_dsa_with_sha1);
algorithms.put("DSAWITHSHA1", X9ObjectIdentifiers.id_dsa_with_sha1);
algorithms.put("SHA224WITHDSA", NISTObjectIdentifiers.dsa_with_sha224);
algorithms.put("SHA256WITHDSA", NISTObjectIdentifiers.dsa_with_sha256);
algorithms.put("SHA384WITHDSA", NISTObjectIdentifiers.dsa_with_sha384);
algorithms.put("SHA512WITHDSA", NISTObjectIdentifiers.dsa_with_sha512);
algorithms.put("SHA1WITHECDSA", X9ObjectIdentifiers.ecdsa_with_SHA1);
algorithms.put("ECDSAWITHSHA1", X9ObjectIdentifiers.ecdsa_with_SHA1);
algorithms.put("SHA224WITHECDSA", X9ObjectIdentifiers.ecdsa_with_SHA224);
algorithms.put("SHA256WITHECDSA", X9ObjectIdentifiers.ecdsa_with_SHA256);
algorithms.put("SHA384WITHECDSA", X9ObjectIdentifiers.ecdsa_with_SHA384);
algorithms.put("SHA512WITHECDSA", X9ObjectIdentifiers.ecdsa_with_SHA512);
algorithms.put("GOST3411WITHGOST3410", CryptoProObjectIdentifiers.gostR3411_94_with_gostR3410_94);
algorithms.put("GOST3411WITHGOST3410-94", CryptoProObjectIdentifiers.gostR3411_94_with_gostR3410_94);
algorithms.put("GOST3411WITHECGOST3410", CryptoProObjectIdentifiers.gostR3411_94_with_gostR3410_2001);
algorithms.put("GOST3411WITHECGOST3410-2001", CryptoProObjectIdentifiers.gostR3411_94_with_gostR3410_2001);
algorithms.put("GOST3411WITHGOST3410-2001", CryptoProObjectIdentifiers.gostR3411_94_with_gostR3410_2001);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Did you add BouncyCastle to the security providers? You can do that with this line:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Comment: Yes, I did, but I neglected to copy it in the snippet I posted here. I'll update it.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is not directly related to BouncyCastle. But, I thought this would be useful for others:

In my case, I was using SpongyCastle. I got a similar problem:
org.e.h.p: cannot create signer: Provider SC does not provide SHA256WITHRSA
at org.e.h.a.a.a(SourceFile:101)

It turned out that proguard was removing some of the required classes. After adding the following in proguard config file:
    -keep class org.spongycastle.** { *; }

the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Bouncy Castle to security providers on Your java platform in two steps:
**1.** Copy BC librarys (currently bcpkix-jdk15on-149.jar, bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar) to directory **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/**
**2.** Register BC provider: edit file **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security**  and under line

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
```

add Your BC provider

```
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Change numbers of rest providers. The whole block of providers should be similar to:

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
security.provider.3=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.4=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.5=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.6=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.7=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.8=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.9=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.10=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
```