# How to sign and validate RSA PKCS#1 v2.0 signatures in Java

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, jce

I'm trying to sign and validate signature in RSA+SHA1 with PKCS1 v2.0 padding.
I haven't found in the documentation (JDK or JCE) which algorithm/padding I have to use. 
It seems that I've to use OAEP padding but I didn't succeed:

For validation, I've tried via Cipher in DECRYPT_MODE with the public key sent by the signer:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA1ANDMGF1PADDING", "SunJCE"); 
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pub); //exception !
```

But I got an exception:

```
  java.security.InvalidKeyException: OAEP cannot be used to sign or verify signatures
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.init(RSACipher.java:303)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineInit(RSACipher.java:207)
    ...
```

(For unknown reason, OAEPWITHSHA1ANDMGF1PADDING is only accepted with ENCRYPT_MODE+PUBLIC KEY or DECRYPT_MODE+PRIVATE KEY, the opposite that I want to do....)

For signature, I'm trying to use Signature but I don't know which algorithm to use:

```
Signature mySig2 = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSAandMGF1");
```

Doesn't work :

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA1withRSAandMGF1 Signature not available
    at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:229)
...
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You're talking about RSA-PSS here which is the equivalent of OAEP for signatures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BouncyCastle does not find algorithms that it provides?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778531/bouncycastle-does-not-find-algorithms-that-it-provides)

Comment: `Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSAandMGF1")` seems to be available from BouncyCastle.

Comment: Also: [what padding strategy is used by SunJCE SHA1WithRSA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42263476/1816580)

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look for RSA-PSS.

Comment: I've look BouncyCastle, the API allow DECRYPT with a public key (in SunJCE implementation, it's only possible to DECRYPT with a private key) so it should work

Comment: I've tried with Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC"); , it seems to do the job, I've succeeded to verify the signature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope I'm not too late to respond to this. Very recently I had to face the same issue with RSA encryption. My Signer wants to do the verification to the data that is sent through POST. This is how I managed to work on that in Java.

Step 1 - Add following into your project

```
bcprov-ext-jdk14-1.45.jar 
commons-codec-1.4.jar
```

Step 2 - Declare your Cipher

```
private Cipher cipher;
```

Step 3 - Call below in your class constructor

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
```

Step 4 - Get your PublicKey from public key text string

```
public PublicKey getPublic(String pubKey) throws Exception {
    byte[] publicBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(pubKey);
    X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
}
```

Step 5 - Verification method

```
public boolean verfyRSA(String signature, String data, PublicKey key) throws Exception {

    byte[] sign = Base64.decodeBase64(signature);
    byte[] dat = Base64.decodeBase64(data);

    Signature rsaVerify = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSAandMGF1");
    rsaVerify.initVerify(key);
    rsaVerify.update(dat);
    return rsaVerify.verify(sign);
}
```

Step 6 - Usage

```
Yourclass yc = new YourClass();
PublicKey publicKey = yc.getPublic("Your PublicKey without leading and trailing -------text------");
boolean b = yc.verfyRSA("POST_Signature", "POST_data", publicKey);
```

Hope this helps. Mind the getInstance() parameters. These are the ones that do the trick. Cheers

Comment: and if my key contains lines like '----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY' etc. Should I remove them?

Comment: @kirill-bazarov ; Yup. remove both leading and trailing -------text------ as i 've mentioned in step 6

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to sign and validate signature in RSA+SHA1 with PKCS1 v2.0 padding.

This is a strange requirement.

First of all, RSA is secure even if PKCS#1 v1.5 compatible padding is used. It is however not secure when SHA-1 is used to hash the input/message, for the simple reasons that SHA-1 is not considered secure anymore for that kind of purpose.

Second, although PKCS#1 v2.0 contains a new padding mode for signature generation called PSS or - to be more precise - RSASSA-PSS it *also* contains the single signature generation mode from 1.5 of the standard called RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5. So *at least in theory* your requirements are not clear.

---

Now PKCS#1 v1.5 padding **for encryption** is known to be broken against padding oracle attacks. For that reason alone, OAEP encryption introduced in PKCS#1 v2.0 is generally available.

PSS for signature generation has a better security proof, but PKCS#1 v1.5 is still considered secure. This is likely why Oracle / SUN didn't include PSS within Java SE JCA. If you want it you can vote for it [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146293).

---

> I haven't found in the documentation (JDK or JCE) which algorithm/padding I have to use. It seems that I've to use OAEP padding but I didn't succeed.

OAEP stands for Optimal Asymmetric **Encryption** Padding. Padding for encryption cannot/should not be used for signature generation.

---

After adding the Bouncy Castle provider the RSA PSS becomes available. You can use your (insecure) scheme with `"SHA1withRSA/PSS"` or indeed the identical `"SHA1withRSAandMGF1"`. It's likely that Oracle's Java SE will support RSA/PSS once the TLS 1.3 specification is finalized.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your precisions. The requirement for the PKCS 1 v2. 0 is given by the editor of a bank application. I ve to build a service which communicate with this application. The files exchanged have to be signef with a pkcs 1 v2

Comment: I'am not an expert in signature and cryptology. I thinked that signing was nearly like doing encryption : encryption of a hash using the private key and decryption of the hash using the public key. But if i understand well your answer, some padding are only use for encryption purpose and other padding are only use for signing. Is it right? Is it possible to validate the signature using Cipher class? (decrypt the data and compare it with the calculated hash)

Comment: Created [especially for this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172). And note that SHA-1 could still be relatively secure for signature generation when the input space is limited; I hope it is! You're welcome :)

Comment: I have read your question in your link : thanks a lot :) It's much clear now. The first thought is not always the one (to think that encrypting and signing is nearly the same thing)

Comment: A stupid question : is it "dangerous" to have a weak hashing method for a signature ? I mean : in a signature, the hash is here for checking integrity of the message but the hash is "protected" by the encryption with the private key, it's very difficult to provide a same hash for a different message.

Comment: The hash is not protected; you can simply "decrypt" using the public key. Even in schemes such as PSS, in the end the hash needs to be compared. Both the modular exponentiation and the padding are reversible by anyone.